# PHP - SQL how to select ids from table and insert into another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I need to do an inner join with the insert into statement. I need to insert data into 2 tables but the id of the records from the second table should also be stored into a column from the first table.

the first sql section makes a new record for every given dj name in the dj table, the second part is supposed to get the id from the added dj and insert it into a column from table "articles".

```
$alle_djs = explode(', ', $this->djs);
foreach ($alle_djs as $elke_dj) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO dj (name) VALUES ( :name_dj )";
  $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $st->bindValue( ":name_dj", $elke_dj, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $st->execute();

  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO articles (dj_ids) SELECT id FROM dj WHERE name=:name_dj";
  $st2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
  $st2->bindValue( ":name_dj", $elke_dj, PDO::PARAM_STR );
  $st2->execute();
}
$conn = null
```

Comment: **[PDO::lastInsertId](http://au.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)**

Comment: Why don't use first sql section as well?

Comment: Use the MySQL function `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO articles(dj_ids) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID())";
```

Comment: Thank you, $conn->lastInsertedId() did it :) Now I only still need to prevent multiple djs with the same name to be stored :)

Comment: If I do that and I update without making any changes, the last insterted id becomes 0 :/

Comment: Solved it if last ids are not equal to 0 I merge the current ids array with the last ids array and that gives me the right result, thanks for your help :)

Comment: When you do an `INSERT`, you can use `$stmt->rowCount` to tell if it inserted anything. This will be `0` if nothing was inserted because of a duplicate.